# Handle `onNewIntent` on Android outside Activity

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm working on an Android library that has push notifications related functionality using Firebase Cloud Messaging API. Most applications that will be using this library are going to have the `launchMode` in their main activities set to `singleTask` or `singleInstance` so I'm not able to get the message information while in background using a reference to an `Activity` with `getIntent`, and since I just have a reference to the `Activity` I cannot override `onNewIntent`.

Is there any way I can access to the `Intent` that is delivered to the application when the user taps to the push notification? I tried using an `IntentService` with no filter but it doesn't seem to catch anything.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is happening when you tap the notification, I mean the whole process.

Comment: rest you can't handle onNewIntent outside the activity.

Comment: You need to work event bus. When you tap notification, some service or activity is listening to that event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed my problem so here's the solution for anybody else might be interested:

I registered a `BroadcastListener` in my manifest that looks like:

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".MyPushNotificationReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

With this I can receive intents for incoming push notifications while in foreground, background or even when the application is not running at all.